# Javascript can't get all length of a string send by mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

I try to print result of a Mysql  with javascript. But when I print the result with javascript, it's just print what is before a space not after for a string with more than one word. Please I need help to solve it.

Here short resume ofr me code

PHP Code:

```
<div class="form-group row">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-4"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <select class="form-control" name="selAssure" id="select4" disabled onchange="affecterselectiona()">
                <option value="aucun" selected="selected">S&eacute;lectionner l'assur&eacute; </option>
                <?php
                $res=mysql_query("select * from assure WHERE assnom= 'Bonjour Hello'");
                while ($ligne=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
                    $val0=trim($ligne['asscode']) ."&curren;". trim($ligne['assid']) ."&curren;". trim($ligne['assnom']) ."&curren;". trim($ligne['assprenom'])."&curren;". trim($ligne['assadresse']) ."&curren;". trim($ligne['assville']) ."&curren;". trim($ligne['asspays']) ."&curren;". trim($ligne['assdatenaissance'])."&curren;". trim($ligne['asssexe']) ."&curren;". trim($ligne['asstelephone']) ."&curren;". trim($ligne['assemail']) ."&curren;". trim($ligne['assfax']);
                    echo "<option value=".$val0.">". trim($ligne['assnom']) ." ". trim($ligne['assprenom']) ."</option>";

                }
                ?>
            </select></div>
    </div>
```

Data base:

```
  `assure` (
  `asscode` double NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `assid` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `assnom` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `assprenom` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `assfax` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`asscode`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM assure WHERE `assnom`= "Bonjour Hello";
```

Resultat of query:

```
asscode = 00001
assid = 00343004504
assnom = "Bonjour Hello"
assprenom = "Henriette"
assadresse = "BP 132"
assville = "Yaounde"
asspays = 8
assdatedenaissance = "1958-04-30"
asssexe = "feminin"
asstelephone = 237687787676
assemail = "beta@gmail.com"
assfax = NULL
```

Here the code to print the result from javascript:

```
function affecterselectiona(){
    var chaineAssure = window.document.formpro.selAssure.value;
    window.alert(chaineAssure);
    var tabassure = chaineAssure.split('¤');
    if (tabassure[8]=="masculin"){
        window.document.formpro.radSexeA[0].checked=true;
    }else{
        window.document.formpro.radSexeA[1].checked=true;
    }
    window.document.formpro.txtCodeA.value=tabassure[0];
    window.document.formpro.txtIdA.value=tabassure[1];
    window.document.formpro.txtNomA.value=tabassure[2];
    ...

}
```

So window.alert(chaineAssure) print:

```
00001¤000010¤Bonjour
```

instead off

```
00001¤000010¤Bonjour Hello¤Henriette¤BP 132¤Yaounde¤8¤1958-04-30¤feminin¤237687787676¤beta@gmail.com¤NULL
```

Hello,
I used json to solve my problem
This is the code:

```
<div class="form-group row">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-4"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <select class="form-control assureselect" name="selAssure" id="select4" disabled onchange="affecterselectionajson()">


                    <option value="aucun" selected="selected">S&eacute;lectionner l'assur&eacute; </option>
                <?php

                    $result = mysql_query("select asscode,  assnom, assprenom from assure WHERE assnom= 'Bonjour Hello' order by asscode") or die('Could not query');

                    $json = array();
                    if (mysql_num_rows($result)) {
                        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
                        while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
                            $test_data[] = $row;
                        }
                        $json['assures'] = $test_data;
                    }
                    $encoded = json_encode($json);
                    $tmp_array = json_decode($encoded);
                    foreach ($tmp_array->assures as $item) {
                        echo "<option value=" . json_encode($item) . ">" . $item[0] . " " . $item[1] . " " . $item[2] . "</option>";
                    }
                ?>


            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here the new javascript

```
function affecterselectionajson(){
    var chaineAssure = window.document.formpro.selAssure.value;
    window.alert(chaineAssure);

}
```

But I'm still have the same problem:

```
window.alert(chaineAssure);
```

Prints :["00001","Bonjour
instead off: ["00001","Bonjour Hello","Henriette"]

So how to solve space inside an item.

Comment: What's this weird business with `'¤'`? Why not just use JSON to return the data from the server?

Comment: Hello @RogerC,
I update the code in the top.

Thanks

Comment: Hello @ADyson,

The '¤' help me to separate the differents fields the row coming from mysql. And that value to javascript who split it as an array.

For JSON, I don't have the solution.

Thanks

Comment: you can easily google how to return data in JSON format using any popular programming language (such as PHP for example using `json_encode()` - you havent said what server-side code you're using, but it looks like PHP). And then it can be instantly translated into a Javascript object with no effort from. Your way is just creating more work for you, and is completely non-standard. Plus there is always the small chance that the user will want to include `'¤'` legitimately in the data (I know I can't think why, but you never know, it's a valid character/symbol)

Comment: Also, why are you using the long-deprecated `mysql_` code library? It was discontinued many years ago and removed entirely in PHP7. No new code should be written using this library. It leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks (due to the lack of parameterised query support) and potentially other unpatched vulnerabilities. Switch to using `mysqli` or `PDO` as soon as possible, and then learn how to write parameterised queries to protect your data from malicious input. See http://bobby-tables.com for a simple explanation of the risks and some sample PHP code to write queries safely.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in this loop :

```
while ($ligne=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
    $val0=trim($ligne['asscode']) ."&curren;". trim($ligne['assid']) ."&curren;". trim($ligne['assnom']) ."&curren;". trim($ligne['assprenom'])."&curren;". trim($ligne['assadresse']) ."&curren;". trim($ligne['assville']) ."&curren;". trim($ligne['asspays']) ."&curren;". trim($ligne['assdatenaissance'])."&curren;". trim($ligne['asssexe']) ."&curren;". trim($ligne['asstelephone']) ."&curren;". trim($ligne['assemail']) ."&curren;". trim($ligne['assfax']);
    echo "<option value=".$val0.">". trim($ligne['assnom']) ." ". trim($ligne['assprenom']) ."</option>";
}
```

1 - There is a typo in here `trim($ligne['assdatenaissance'])`, assdatenaissance is not an entry in your array. It should be `trim($ligne['assdatedenaissance'])`

2 - You are printing that string in the `value` parameter of your `<option>`, you're not using any quote to encapsulate this value. You end up with this HTML code :

```
<option value=1¤59509060¤Bonjour Hello¤Henriette¤BP 132¤Yaounde¤8¤1958-04-30¤feminin¤237687787676¤beta@gmail.com¤>
```

Which is equivalent to :

```
 <option value="1¤59509060¤Bonjour" Hello¤Henriette¤BP 132¤Yaounde¤8¤1958-04-30¤feminin¤237687787676¤beta@gmail.com¤>
```

You need to use a string separator to encapsulate the value of your value parameter :

```
while ($ligne=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
    $val0=trim($ligne['asscode']) ."&curren;". trim($ligne['assid']) ."&curren;". trim($ligne['assnom']) ."&curren;". trim($ligne['assprenom'])."&curren;". trim($ligne['assadresse']) ."&curren;". trim($ligne['assville']) ."&curren;". trim($ligne['asspays']) ."&curren;". trim($ligne['assdatenaissance'])."&curren;". trim($ligne['asssexe']) ."&curren;". trim($ligne['asstelephone']) ."&curren;". trim($ligne['assemail']) ."&curren;". trim($ligne['assfax']);
    echo "<option value='$val0'>". trim($ligne['assnom']) ." ". trim($ligne['assprenom']) ."</option>";
}
```

**On a side note :** As others have said in comments, I advise you to look for a different way to exchange data between the different layers of your application. For instance, your PHP/MySQL code could be returning JSON and JavaScript could deal with this data as JavaScript objects, instead of managing complicated strings. 
Handling strings the way you do is going to create a lot of headache.

In french, since I notice your code is french : 
Je vous conseille de ne pas manipuler des chaines de caractères pour échanger des données entre les bouches PHP/MySQL et Javascript. Il serait préférable que le code PHP génère un objet Javascript au format JSON et que celui soit manipulé ensuite par les fonctions JavaScript. Manipuler des chaines de caractères avec des séparateurs maison risque de créer beaucoup de problèmes.

Comment: Hello @RogerC,

J'ai fait une mise a jour de mon code en utilisant json, j'ai toujours un soucis avec l'espace pour les champs ayants plus d'un mot.
PLus haut j'ai mis le code utilisé.

Merci

Comment: Il y a toujours le même problème car il faut mettre, dans le tag option, la valeur du paramètre value entre guillemets simples : echo "<option value='$val0'>"...